# Access function of containing Canvas from contained children / User Control

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a C# metro (store) app which has a UI similar to the following code (as an example) :

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
<Image x:Name="image" Canvas.Left="600" Canvas.Top="170"/>
</Canvas>
```

The containing canvas has a function "AddToLog(string text)" and I want this function to be accessible by the objects inside the canvas (i.e. here "image") also. The image may also be a User Control contained in a separate *.xaml file.  Is this possible, and if so how would I go about doing it ? If not, are there any alternate ways to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get containing `Canvas` from `Image`'s `Parent` property :

```
var canvas = (Canvas)image.Parent;
//at this point you're able to access any function defined in Canvas
//canvas.AddToLog("something");
```

Comment: How can I access a function defined in the class `MainPage : Page` from a function in a separate `UserControl.xaml` file ?

Comment: if you meant in the same situation (where `MainPage` is parent of `UserControl`) then you can still use `Parent` property...